# How to enable automatic login in alpine linux for root

Tags: terminal, alpine-linux, agetty

I am trying to set up an alpine linux machine that needs to run an user program at the startup.

I did not add any user except for root.

After searching for solution of how to enable automatic login i have found instructions that said i need to use agetty. In order:

1. `apk add util-linux` to add agetty.
2. `cd /etc/init.d && ln -s agetty agetty.tty1` to add agetty service for the terminal.
3. `cd /etc/conf.d && cp agetty agetty.tty1` to add configuration.
4. `nano agetty.tty1` or use other editor to add "--autologin $USER --noclear" to agetty options
5. `rc-update add agetty.tty1` to ensure launch at start.

One thing that bothered me was the fact instruction told about turning off previous agetty service before adding new, changed one - and there was no agetty service enabled.

However, things went wrong: during machine start i could see output of the automatic login before several services (chrony and some other) were started, and then i got another login prompt that did not work anymore. it seemed as there were bno two logins/terminals and system became unworkable.

What was my error and how can i fix this?

Comment: Is this a Docker Container?

Comment: No, just a standalone computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "automatic login" you mean "I'd like a root shell without a password", the easiest way to do that is to add something like this to `/etc/inittab`:

```
tty1::respawn:/bin/sh
```

That will spawn a root shell instead of a login prompt on the given terminal.

---

To accomplish the same thing using `agetty`, do exactly what you've done in your question, but don't forget to *disable* the existing getty service defined in `/etc/inittab`:

```
sed -i '/tty1/ s/^/#/`
```

Which should get you:

```
#tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

And then reboot (or `kill -HUP 1` to reload `/etc/inittab`).